# como no repetir números aleatorios en el algoritmo burbuja

Tags: java, algoritmos

muy buenas como están si me pueden ayudar les agradecería mucho ocurre y pasa que es algo urgente bueno tengo el método de no repetir los números pero no me funciona si me pueden colaborar la idea es que no se repita los números `random` en el algoritmo de organización `burbuja`

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class randomYburbuja {
    
    public static void main(String... args) {
    
            int[] result = random();
    
            Burbuja(result);

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    
        }
    
        public static int[] random () {
            
            Random r = new Random();
        
            int[] vector = new int[r.nextInt(100000) + 1000];
    
            for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {

                vector[i] = r.nextInt(100000) + 1;
              
            }
            
            int result []=new int[vector.length];
            int b = vector.length ;
            
            for(int i=0;i<vector.length;i++){
            
            int num=r.nextInt(b);
            result[i]= vector[num];
            vector [num]=vector[b-1];
            b--;
            
            }
            
            return result;

        }
    
        public static void Burbuja(int[] v) {
    
            for (int j = 0; j < v.length; j++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < v.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (v[i] > v[i + 1]) {
                        int aux = v[i];
                        v[i] = v[i + 1];
                        v[i + 1] = aux;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando el metodo [ints](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) de la clase `Random` seguido de [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) podes obtener un array de numeros aleatorios sin repetirse.

//como ejemplo este array obtendra 10 numeros aleatorios diferentes del 1 al 100

```
int [] aleatorios=new Random().ints(1,100).distinct().limit(10).toArray();
System.out.println (Arrays.toString (aleatorios));
Burbuja (aleatorios);
System.out.println (Arrays.toString (aleatorios));
```

Comment: listo manito gracias

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta ,dale ✓ ,saludos :)